# Which software is best for small photoediting features?

Tags: windows, graphics

I want the software which is lightweight.

Where can I add some text, mark some areas and cut some portion to save as a new photo?

I have Photoshop, but that's too heavy to do a small job like this.

OS: Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some text, mark some areas and cut some portion to save as a new photo?

**[Fotografix](http://lmadhavan.com/software/fotografix/)** and **[PhotoFiltre](http://photofiltre.free.fr/download_en.htm)** are two excellent lightweight image editors, certainly capable of that.

*Both programs are freeware and portable.*

Edit: here are some PhotoFiltre Toolbars. From left to right: Selection tools, Paintbrush tools, Advanced Paintbrush tools.

[image]

Comment: photofiltre is good but i can't drag the photos into it and other thing is if iwant to mark the particular thing on photo i can't seen to fina brush to mark things

Comment: well, i can drag photos from explorer into PhotoFiltre, no problem. the selection tool is enabled by default (the mouse pointer icon in the right hand toolbar), there are also a variety of other selection tools: ellipse, triangle, various rectangles and a 'lasso'

Comment: added a screenshots with the various toolbars.

Comment: wow that is excellent , i missed the right toolbar i was looking at top only. this is really good. Molly the winner

Answer (score 13):

Use [Paint.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET).

Comment: Try again Molly :P

Comment: (swear filter) :D

Comment: Can't imagine why they're using frames.

Comment: Another nice thing about Paint.net is that it doesn't come with every graphics effect or feature out there, just the basics.  You add them as/if needed, one example I can think of is a gradient tool.

Comment: Best part of Paint.net is the horde of community built plug-ins that you can add to extend it's functionality.  And it's a truly top-notch piece of software.

Answer (score 5):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.ca/) is not only an image viewer, but it also has simple editing capabilities. It is extremely lightweight (1.3MB download).

[image]

IrfanView is freeware.

Comment: Actually i use irfan view currently. can i add text in photos

Comment: Yes, draw a shape anywhere on the image with the mouse, then under the **Edit** option in the menu bar, click **Insert text into selection**.

Comment: can i move text after writing text

Comment: You can move a selection yes

Answer (score 1):

It's open source, and high quality: [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/), seems to work with all versions of Windows I've ever worked with. It depends on the .NET Framework:

> Paint.NET is free image and photo
>   editing software for computers that
>   run Windows. It [features](http://www.getpaint.net/features.html) an intuitive
>   and innovative user interface with
>   support for layers, unlimited undo,
>   special effects, and a wide variety of
>   useful and powerful tools. An active
>   and growing [online community](http://www.getpaint.net/redirect/forum.html) provides
>   friendly help, [tutorials](http://www.getpaint.net/redirect/tutorials.html), and [plugins](http://www.getpaint.net/redirect/plugins.html).

Comment: this has already been recommended, you should upvote the existing answer if you wish to second it, rather than posting the same answer again.

Comment: Hey, we need **one** with the correct links :P

Comment: well, if a link is incorrect, or if you have more information you wish to contribute, then you may leave a comment, like John did. :P

Comment: hehe, what's wrong with my link? i actually have gimp too, but the loading time is just like win startup, thus i use most of the editing on paint.net and only vy vy vy vy vy heavy stuff on gimp.

Answer (score 0):

[Faststone Maxview](http://www.faststone.org/FSMaxViewDetail.htm) is the fastest draw around [sorry for the pun]. Can do what you ask and is very easy to use. Shareware, available as portable.

Their [image viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm) is freeware, and seems able to do most of what you might want but I've not used it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

> I have photoshop but thats too heavy to do samll job like this

When I don't want to open up Photoshop I have two alternate image editors that I like to use:

- The first is [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) [as mentioned by John T above](https://superuser.com/questions/84401/which-software-is-best-for-small-photoediting-features/84405#84405). I tend to use this for cropping and highlighting elements in screen shots. It's super lightweight and easy to use.
- The second is called [Artweaver](http://www.artweaver.de/). If you are comfortable using Photoshop then using Artweaver will be super easy as they have borrowed heavily from the Photoshop interface. The free version of artweaver supports layers which I find particularly useful for doing slightly more advanced tweaking of my images than irfanview allows.

[Lifehacker review of Artweaver](http://lifehacker.com/5048433/photoshop-alternative-artweaver-helps-edit-your-images)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Aviary](http://aviary.com/) has many free online tools including an image editor.

Answer (score 0):

For small jobs like that, I use Paint. It's already part of Windows, so you don't need to install or change anything